# "Shaadh" vs. "Munkar" Hadith

Tags: hadith, arabic, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

In [hadith science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_studies), among the branches of weak ahadith are two types classified as "shaadh" (doubtful, shady) and "munkar" (evil).

These two types both refer to a hadith that contradicts a well-known strong body of hadith, such as the 18 narrations of a sahaba praying alone with Rasulullah (salallahu alayhi wa sallam) and being instructed to pray on his **right** side, and one narration where the sahaba was instructed to pray on his **left** side (the latter being a munkar hadith).

But what exactly is the shade of difference between these two types of hadith?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#Other_types_of_weakness):

> ***Munkar:*** Munkar, (مُنْكَر), literally means 'denounced'. According to
>   Ibn Hajar, if a narration which goes against another authentic hadith
>   is reported by a weak narrator, it is known as munkar. Traditionists
>   as late as Ahmad used to simply label any hadith of a weak reporter as
>   munkar.[15]
>
> ***Shādhdh:*** Shādhdh, (شاذّ), literally means 'anomalous'. According to
>   al-Shafi'i, a shādhdh hadith is one which is reported by a trustworthy
>   person who contradicts the narration of a person more reliable than he
>   is. It does not include a hadith which is unique in its matn and is
>   not narrated by someone else.[15]

The main difference is that the former is reported by a weak narrator while the latter is reported by a trustworthy person. There is also other kinds of weakness.