# Is this description of God by Ali regarded as valid by Sunni Muslims?

Tags: hadith, sunni, authenticity, ali

I stumbled upon this description of Allah by 'Ali bin Abi Talib and wanted to know if it is regarded as valid by Sunni Muslims:

> Imam 'Ali bin Abi Talib, the great jurist, said the following in response to their questions:
>
> O Assembly of Jews, listen to me. Do not be concerned about asking
> anyone but me in this affair.
>  My Lord – Mighty and Majestic – He
> is the First, without beginning
>  He is neither intermingled with
> His Creation
>  Nor is He in a state in between that
>  He is not a
> ghost or spirit that is remote
>  He is not remote where He does not
> know His Creation
>  He did not appear at some point where it could
> be said He is created
>  No, Majestic is He that He be decribed in
> this way when He has given all things their shape
>  He has always
> been and does not change through time
>  He was – when there was no
> thing – without time or place
>  And He is now as He ever was!
>  He
> is not distracted by different affairs
>  How can He be decribed as
> are ghosts and how can He be truly praised by people?
>  How can this
> be when He is not within things so as to be called separate?
>  He is
> without likeness and how yet He is closer to you than your jugular
> vein!
>  He is as far as can be from any likeness with the
> creation
>  The slightest thing from His Creation is not hidden from
> Him
>  Whether it is the slightest statement off the tongue, the
> hidden action or the single footstep
>  In the great shadows of the
> night, the shining of the moon, the brightness of the sun, nothing is
> hidden from Him when He is the source of light for all things.
>  He
> surrounds all in His Creation, whether it is the sudden onset of night
> or the sudden brightness of the day without His being encompassed by
> the creation.
>  He knows about every place and all of what is and
> will be
>  And also the end of all things that are to come
>  Time
> and ending is something that has been given to the creation.
> Limits are only attributed to created things and not Him.
>  He did
> not create the things from the foundations of eternity where they
> always existed
>  Nor did He create from existing things already
> present.
>  No! Rather He created what He made and established its’
> creation from nothing.
>  He gave shape and good form to
> everything.
>  He is One and Unique in His Oneness
>  There is
> nothing the creation can do that can harm Him and there is no way the
> creation can benefit Him
>  He is quick to answer the supplications
> of those that call upon Him
>  Yes, indeed the angels in the skies
> and earths obey Him.
>  His knowledge of all that has died or ceased
> is just as full as His knowledge of all things living and what is in
> the highest skies.
>  The same holds true for His knowledge in every
> thing and all the voices and languages do not confuse or baffle
> Him.
>  He hears all the different  voices and languages without
> limbs or organs
>  Indeed He is the Designer and the All Seeing, The
> Knower of all affairs, All Living, Self Sufficient
>  Glorified be
> He, He spoke to Musa directly without the need of limbs and
> instruments, lips or throat.
>  Glorified and Exalted is He from
> having a similarity like the creations.
>  Whoever claims that Our
> God has boundaries, then He does not know the Creator that is
> worshipped
>  The same is said of the one who says that the places
> encompass Him
>  This claim means that He is mingled with and
> contained by the creation!
>  No, He surrounds and encompasses every
> place.
>  The one that claims He is surrounded by His Creation when
> he describes the Most Merciful while He has no revelation or text to
> prove this, I have this question for him:
>  Describe for me (angel)
> Jibril, Mika’il, Israfil! Go ahead! I defy you to do so!
>  Are you
> then unable to describe what is a creation like you?
>  Are you
> unable to describe just a creation when you describe the Creator with
> form and organs, this same One who is neither overtaken by sleep nor
> slumber!
>  This is the same One who owns all that is in the skies
> and the earths, what is between them! He is the Lord of the Glorious
> Throne!

Sourced from: [SplendidPearls.org](https://splendidpearls.org/2013/02/03/who-is-god-what-is-god-the-response-of-imam-ali-bin-abi-talib/), 2013.

It is contained in a 'book of saints', Hilyat ul- Awliya wa Tabaqat-ul-Asfiya ([حلية الأولياء وطبقات الأصفياء](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=628&pid=138254&hid=222)) [volume 1, pages 72-73](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=65&idto=65&bk_no=131&ID=72), written by Imam Abu Nu`aym Ahmad Asfahani أبو نعيم الأصبهاني who lived in 336AH - 430AH.

Source:

Are there any other recorded instances of this description? How do we know that Ali really said this, and that this was not something later Muslims attributed to him.

Comment: I don't know how Sunnis view this. But these descriptions fully resonate with descriptions attributed to Ali ibn Abi Talib in Shia sources such as Nahj al-Baligha and Usul al-Kafi.

Comment: This needs a Hadith science researcher to verify the authenticity of the sanad (series of narrators) as well as the matn (body) of this narration (unless somebody has already done so).

Comment: @TamerShlash nope it would need somebody who has knowledge in 'ilm al-Kalam or theology ('Aqidah: Ash'arite, Maturidi, Salafi ...)! As OP isn't interested in the authenticity of that statement.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I agree, but IMHO the best way to give an answer here is to bring what scholars said about that narration and it's narrators. If it's already a weak narration, why even bother discussing it's validity?

Comment: @TamerShlash that would be among the tasks of the person who finds or gives an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but I thought I could just share what I found about it so far (may update it later if I find out something new). **Please take it with a big grain of salt.**

First, let's bring the sanad (narrators chain) of this hadith to make things more easier:

> حدثنا أبو بكر أحمد بن محمد بن الحارث ، ثنا الفضل بن الحباب الجمحي ، ثنا مسدد ، ثنا عبد الوارث بن سعيد ، عن محمد بن إسحاق ، عن النعمان بن سعد
>
> Narrating Abu-Bakr Ahmad bin Muhammad bin Al-Harith, narrating Al-Fadhl bin Al-Habbab Al-Jumhi, narrating Masdad, narrating Abdul-warith bin Saeed, narrating Muhammad bin Isaac, narrating **Al-Nu'man** bin Saad

In the same book referenced in the question (Hilyat ul- Awliya wa Tabaqat-ul-Asfiya), the author, Abu Nu`aym Asfahani mentions the following right after the narration:

> هذا حديث غريب من حديث النعمان ، كذا رواه ابن إسحاق عنه مرسلا.
>
> This hadith is a [gharib hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7952/167) in the level or Al-Nu'man (one of the men in the sanad/narrator chain of this hadith). And that's how bin Isaac narrated it from him (Al-Nu'man) as a [Mursal](https://islamqa.info/en/130686) hadith.

It is important to note that Mursal hadiths are usually considered as weak (Da'if) hadiths.

Also, in his book العلو للعلي الغفار, Al-Dhahabi mentioned this hadith and this is what he said about it:

> هَذَا حَدِيثٌ مُنْكَرٌ ، وَإِسْنَادُهُ غَيْرُ ثَابِتٍ ، لَكِنَّهُ صَالِحٌ صَحَّ إِلَى عَبْدِ الْوَارِثِ
>
> This hadith is [Munkar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43/167), and it's narrators chain is not stable, though it's correct and valid until Abdul-warith.

[Source](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=942&pid=328901&hid=126)

So regardless of the matn/content of the hadith itself and whether different schools (Salafi, Ash'ari, Maturidi) agree to it or not, the authenticity of the hadith itself is concerning.